# Is there a word to refer to both clients and providers?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm searching for a word that i can use to refer to both clients and providers right now, i'm thinking of 'associate'.
For example: In the place i work, the _______ can be self-employed people or companies.

Is there a more accurate word?

Comment: I wouldn't use the word _associate_, that is used mostly to describe people who are working together or for the same organisation.

Comment: Welcome to the EL&U. You've attached the single-word-request tag to your question; please look at the information page for the tag and edit your question to include the requested info. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**business partner**

From [wikipedia.org...](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_partner)

> A business partner is a commercial entity with which another commercial entity has some form of alliance.

"Alliance" throws it off a bit, but what's an alliance in business anyway?

Further on the article, it states that business partners can be clients or suppliers.

Answer (score 0):

from https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stakeholder

**stakeholder**

noun

2 A person with an interest or concern in something, especially a business